# How to display this message within the correct row, not within all rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code where it is displaying the delete message but it is displaying it in each row, this is incorrect, it should on;y be displayed in the row the file was deleted from:

```
   var counter = 0;

function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){

      var result = '';
      counter++;

      if (success == 1){
         result = '<span class="imagemsg'+counter+'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>';      
         $('.listImage').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).append('<div>' + htmlEncode(imagefilename) + '<button type="button" class="deletefileimage" image_file_name="' + imagefilename + '">Remove</button><br/><hr/></div>'); 
      }
      else {
         result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
      }


      $(".deletefileimage").on("click", function(event) {

         var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

    jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
      .done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg" + counter).html(data);
       });

       $(this).parent().remove();

    });

      return true;   
}
```

The result variable is called here in the imageupload.php:

CALLBACK:

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

Here is the link to the application [here](https://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php).

Please do this, click on the "Add" button twice, in both rows use the file inputs to upload an image. In both rows it will state that file upload was a success and it will display a name of both file at the bottom of their respective rows. Now delete a file by clicking on the delete button, you will see that the message (File was Deleted) is displayed in both rows, it should only be displayed within the row the file was deleted from

Comment: And where is `result` being used?

Comment: $result is in a seperate page using a callback function. I included this at bottom of question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are initializing counter inside the function it will be a local variable, therefore the value will be ZERO every time. You need to initialize it outside of the function.

Comment: I moved it out of the function but it is still doing same thing. I updated code above to show what current code now looks like

Comment: var counter = 0; needs to be outside the function in order to make it a global variable.

Comment: or do `if (typeof window.counter === "undefined") window.counter = 0;`

Comment: I updated code and application. I put the counter++ back in the function. The problem is that lets say there are 3 rows. When you delete a file in either row, the delete message is shown in the second row only.  It doesn't matter is there are 4, 5 or 6 rows the message is only being displayed in the second row only. Why is this?

Comment: If you delete a row, wouldn't you then need to decrement the counter?

Comment: @Diodeus I am not deleting a row, I am just deleting the name of the file within a row. Whichever row contains the name of the file will be the row that displays the delete message.

Comment: You need to set "counter" to the current row number when deleting.

Comment: @Diodeus Here is an example of what I mean. If I have 3 rows, and I upload dog.png in row 1, frog.png in row 2 and cat.png in row 3, then their file names and the "Remove" button will be displayed within their rows (so dog.png is append in row 1, frog.png in row 2 and cat.png in row 3) If I click on the "Remove" button for dog.png, then as it is in row 1, then only row 1 would display the message "dog.png was Deleted". If I then remove the file cat.png which is on row 3, then only row 3 would display the message "cat.png was Deleted" etc. Hopefully you now understand what  I want to achieve